# How to run vba code only in weekdays

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a macro daily but it should first check whether toady is weekday or weekend. If Weekday the run the code else exit sub.

Below is the code :

```
Dim checkday As Variant
    checkday = Format(Date, "dddd")
    If checkday <> "=Weekday" Then
    MsgBox ("Selected date is a Weekend, Thus report cannot be generated!!!")
    Exit Sub
End If

Rest of the code ...
```

Comment: `If WeekDay(today) > 2 Then`

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works !! I also have an another question if i want to customize the date (Instead of today, I need to give a specific cell value which is a date) what will be the code !!

Comment: `If WeekDay(Range("A1")) > 2 Then`

Comment: [By default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/weekday-function), Sunday is the first day of the week which makes Saturday the seventh day. You can override the default, like this: `If Weekday(Now, vbSaturday) > 2 Then` or `If Weekday(Now, vbMonday) < 6 Then`

Comment: Thanks "barrowc" for the answer !! it worked !! @Tim Williams i have doubt your condition gives me "True" even in "Saturdays and in Mondays" I am not sure whether i made a mistake or missed something. Just wanted to let you know !!!

Comment: I hadn't included the optional second argument, as explained by @barrowc.  It happened to work correctly with my system settings but including the second argument is more robust.

Comment: Okay !! Thank you for your timely Help !!